# Unable to get oauth_verifier for Magento2.0

Tags: magento2, oauth

I am unable to get `oauth_verifier` for Magento2.0 which is needed to get the **access_token**

I am trying to get the access token using POST /oauth/token/access which requires oauth_vefirier as one of the parameter.

I am refereeing [this](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-oauth.html) doc.

Can anybody please let me know from where we can get the oauth_verifier generated by the Magento?

Answer (score 0):

> Open the System > Extensions > Integrations

[image]

> Add New Integration

[image]

> Set the integration **Name** and other settings, then specify your
>   Magento 2 back-end password in the **Your Password** field

[image]

> Switch to the **API** sidebar tab and select the resources which will
>   be available to **OAuth clients**:

[image]

> Press the **Save** button. The **integration** will be saved and the
>   **Integrations** list will be shown again. Press the **Activate** link in the integration row:

[image]

> A confirmation screen will be shown. Press the **Allow** button

[image]

> The credentials screen will be shown.
>     Use them in your third-party software to access your Magento 2 as OAuth server.
>
> **You will see:**
>
> - Consumer Key
> - Consumer Secret
> - Access Token
> - Access Token Secret
>
> Copy it to somewhere, then press the **Done** button.

[image]

> The integration will be saved and the **Integrations** list will be
>   shown again. You will see your integration in the **Active** state:
>   [image]